# How do I make a dynamic cli like the top command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to make a program that will display dynamic data in the way the "top" command does but, I haven't been able to find out how to make the command line interface work. Does anyone know of some resources for building that type of interface?

Comment: Use [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html)

Comment: To expand on @IporSircer's comment: `top` is what is called a *character cell* or full-screen application. Character cell application are sort-of halfway between command-line applications (which consume and produce text) and graphical applications (which use a bitmapped display). In UNIX-like operating systems, such full screen / character cell applications (for example, the editor `vim`, the web browser `lynx`, the file manager `mc` or the package management tool `aptitude`) are built using libraries named `curses` (the old original) or `ncurses` (the less old reimplementation).

Comment: @AlexP, please post that as an answer; it's useful and informative.

Comment: Use `select(2)` to wait for keyboard input or timeout https://linux.die.net/man/2/select